# How can i take the objects inside in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this Result :

`["572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c", "2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"]`
But i would like to have only :

`"572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c", "2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"`

Is this Possible ?

I would like to delete the Array and only have the raw data from inside the Array

Comment: What you mean by that. You want to display `"572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c", "2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"` to console or screen?

Comment: It seems like you have an array with 2 strings, not objects. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: @MaheerAli on screen, i have this in console, but i would like to show in both sides.

Comment: array.toString() will give you the two values with a comma between them

Comment: @David_roman do you want to display the quotes (`"`) also? What about the comma? I assume you want to display `572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c 2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join()` and join the array of string with `,` also use `map()` to add `""` around string

```js
const arr = ["572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c", "2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"]

console.log(arr.map(x => `"${x}"`).join(','))
```

Comment: @mplungjan didn't work with toString(), i tried multiple times..

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method will coerce all array elements to `string` type and give you the entire array as a single string with elements separated by comma:

```js
const arr = ["572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c", "2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"];

const arr_toString = arr.toString();
// "572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c,2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"
```

If you want the array as single string separated by comma and **each element wrapped by ""**:

```js
const arr = ["572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c", "2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"];

const wanted_result = arr.map(elm => `"${elm}"`).toString();
// "572a2b2c-e495-4f98-bc0a-59a5617b488c","2d50c44a-0f94-478b-91b6-bb0cd8287e70"
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) executes whatever function you supply on all the elements of the array and return the returned value of the function. So the function I used is:

`` elm => `"${elm}"` ``  - which takes each `elm` and return it wrapped by ""